# Error en web.config en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Buenas quisiera que me ayuden estoy ejecutando este archivo pero me sale un error en el web.config yo estoy usando el visual studio 2013 y creo que anterior lo habrían echo con el visual studio 2005. El error me sale como la imagen quisiera que me ayuden por favor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53419/discussion-on-question-by-pierro-error-en-web-config-en-c).

Answer (score 1):

La ddl que busca vs2013 no la encuentra. Lo que yo haría seria preguntar si el proyecto que estas modificando esta publicado en algún servidor IIS. Si es así, pregunta si puedes obtener las dlls faltantes, y agregarlas manualmente a tu proyecto. 
Después de agregarlas no se te olvide registrarla en windows.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que faltan las librerías y no están referenciadas en el proyecto. En este caso `CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.dll` (y supongo que el resto de `CrystalDecisions.*.dll` tampoco.

Si la aplicación estaba funcionando en algún sitio, en la carpeta `bin` de la misma deberían de estar (con un poco de suerte). Si no, en la máquina que la estaba ejecutando estarán registradas en el registro de ensamblados. Se pueden copiar usando la linea de comandos y mirando en la carpeta `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL`.

Una vez ubicadas, cópialas en una carpeta donde está la solución y desde Visual Studio añade una referencia directamente a esas DLLs.

Si esto no funciona, es posible que tengas que conseguir el instalador de las DLLs de Crystal Reports con la versión específica (es decir, el `CCRedist2008_xxx.msi` que hay en la imagen.